# PANDAS TO_HTML conditional FORMATTING

Tags: python, html, pandas

I have a daily Pivot Table that I export to HTML

[image]

The code I use to create it is

```
HEADER = '''
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .df tbody tr:last-child { background-color: #FF0000; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
'''
FOOTER = '''
    </body>
</html>
'''

with open("/home/testing_libs/htmlex.html", 'w') as f:
    f.write(HEADER)
    f.write(pivot1.to_html(classes='pivot1'))
    f.write(FOOTER)
```

The source is a PANDAs dataframe. I would like to create logic with PANDAs to have a column which does NOT appear in the Pivot table, but determines the color of the Pivot cells for Units. In other words, if I compare today's Pivot, or even its precursor Dataframe in terms of 'units', from the previous day, and the current day's 'units' are smaller, then I want that CELL in HTML 'RED' and not black. 
I don't know whether I can have HTML colored red based on NOT the 'units' values, but the associated positive/negative value comparing the same GROUP's 'units' values.
Here is the dataframe that creates the above PIVOT TABLE

```
    widget  region  industry    units
0   oldschool   middle  tech    10
1   newschool   west    manufacturing   40
2   upandcomer  east    manufacturing   50
3   oldschool   west    manufacturing   40
4   newschool   east    manufacturing   30
5   upandcomer  middle  manufacturing   20
6   oldschool   middle  manufacturing   10
7   newschool   east    tech    30
8   upandcomer  east    tech    30
```

THEN to create PIVOT

```
pivot1 = pd.pivot_table(frame1,index=['region','widget','industry'])
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `np.where(condition, ifConditionTrue, ifConditionFalse)` from numpy to update `pivot1['units']` depending on the comparison against another column (or series) where you store previous day's units and `.map()` to colour the output with [ANSI colour codes](http://pueblo.sourceforge.net/doc/manual/ansi_color_codes.html), eg.:

```
pivot1['units'] = np.where( (pivot1['units'] < pivot0['units']), (pivot1['units'] = pivot1['units'].map(lambda x: "\x1b[41m"+str(x)+"\x1b[m")), (pivot1['units'].map(lambda x: str(x)))
```

where `pivot1` is the current day's dataframe, `pivot0` is the previous day's dataframe, and the strange prefix and suffix are the ANSI colour code for black text on red background.

This, however, will make your 'units' integer values intro strings and thus make comparison between days impossible unless you convert them back to integers – so that's not the best strategy to use on your primary dataframe. I suggest regenerating it under a different name for HTML export.

```
pivot1_export = pivot1
pivot1_export['units'] = np.where( (pivot1['units'] < pivot0['units']), (pivot1_export['units'] = pivot1['units'].map(lambda x: "\x1b[41m"+str(x)+"\x1b[m")), (pivot1_export['units'].map(lambda x: str(x)))
```

You can repeat this strategy to add more colours for higher, unchanged, or specific values.

Comment: Thanks this is good. But I've just also realized that in order to do the compare, the dataframes from today/yesterday must be same size. And so the groupings will differ by day; yesterday for instance, the East Region may have had no 'newschool' widget. So currently I get an Error, ValueError: Series lengths must match to compare

Comment: In this setup I would keep the df dimensions stable, eg. filling rows for empty widgets with zeroes – unless they differ over time, ie. new come and old go away.